# What is the difference in database of magento C.E 1.8 when compare with magento C.E 1.7?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8

Is there any difference in database of magento C.E 1.8 when compare with magento C.E 1.7?

Whether in structure or fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the SQL Dumps from Magento 1.7.0.2 and 1.8.1.0

https://gist.github.com/SchumacherFM/10363112

Use any diff tool for comparison. There are many changes.

Most important fix is that this

`` `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'Created At', ``

has been fixed, that means CURRENT_TIMESTAMP has been removed.